# React useEffect hook don't see location after redirect with useNavigate hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a problem with the useEffect hook. I have an application that allows you to search in the header component. This is an example of how I do it

Hader.tsx

```
    const handleKeyDown = async (event: any) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const search: SearchModel = {
        title: searchTitle,
        priceFrom: null,
        priceUntil: null,
        getCount: null,
        skipCount: null
      }
      navigate(ApplicationRoutes.SearchRoute, {state: search});
    }
  }
```

Once on the search page I have this code to get the location, form a route, and then send a request to the api

SearchView.tsx

```
export const SearchView = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<SellItemModel[]>();
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const getData = async (params: SearchModel) => {
    const result = await SearchItemService.SearchByParams(params);
    setItems(result);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
    const params: SearchModel = state;


    getData(params).catch(console.error);
  }, [state]);

...
}
```

When I add a debugger point to useEffect, it works correctly. But without this, the state is zero.

This is the case with the debugger point
[image: example with debugger point]

This case is without a breakpoint
[image: example without debugger point]

I realized that this is due to some rendering states or so on, but I don't really understand how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the code you've shared. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you are seeing that we could inspect live?

Comment: Yes, here is the link to the sandbox. This is my open source project for the university, so feel free to comment on it.
[link to sandbox](https://shorturl.at/pruyz)

https://github.com/yborisovp/mam-web

Comment: That sandbox link is to a URL shortener.

Comment: This link should work, sorry [link](https://t.ly/nRjq)

Comment: I can't seem to get your sandbox running. Is there a way for you to pare it down to a more minimal demo that simply reproduces the issue you are seeing with the component lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research, I fixed the issue with parameters. The problem was in useLocation hook. I've replaced it by useSearchParameters hook, that comes with react router 6 and now I do not have any troubles with it. Still have to rendering calls of useEffect but main issue is solved!